# Insert new item in collection in Hibernate -> Ehcache-entry will be completely made empty

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have container type, with a collection of items, and  tiems with a reference to the container.

For my question it doesn't matter which side of the relation manages the persistence, the collection side or the reference side.

```
Container c=new Container(12L);
Item i=new Item(1L);
Item i2=new Item(2L);
i.setContainer(c);
c.addItem(i);
i2.setContainer(c);
c.addItem(i2);


session.save(c);
session.save(i);
session.save(i2);


tx.commit();
```

Then in a new session I iterate over the collection, the collection will be in Ehcache then, as [1L,2L],

```
c=session.get(Container.class,12L);
Set<Item>items=c.getItems();
Iterator<Item>iterator=items.iterator();
```

Then in a new session I create a new Item, add it to the collection,

```
c=session.get(Container.class,12L);

Item i3=new Item(3L);
i3.setContainer(c);
c.getItems().add(i3);
session.save(i3);


tx.commit();
```

In the database a new row will be inserted in the items table, with a foreign key to the row in the container table, so this is OK.

But in Ehcache the [1L,2L] is removed, en no new value is added, so the Ehcache entry is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are my mapping to Hibernate files:

```
<class
        name="Container"
>
        <cache
                usage="read-write"/>
        <id
                name="id"
                column="id__"
        >
        <set
                name="items"
                inverse="true"
        >
                <cache usage="read-write"/>
                <key
                        column="container_"
                        not-null="true"
                ></key>
                <one-to-many class="Item"/>
        </set>
 </class>




<class
        name="Item"
>
        <cache
                usage="read-write"/>
        <id
                name="id"
                column="id_"
        >

        <many-to-one
                name="container"
                column="container_"
                not-null="false"

        >
        </many-to-one>
 </class>
```

Comment: Show the domain classes if ur using annotations. If you are using xml to define relations then show xml file

Comment: Added the Hibernate mapping files.